# Server hacked: How do I fix, diagnosis and prevent?

Tags: wordpress, hacking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I deal with a compromised server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server)

WP Site (up to date with version & plug ins)
Cheap budget host

Inserted on all of my pages inside the  tags are the following code

> Fast Cash Advance [Fast Cash Advance](http://crappyspamwebsite.com/)if(document.getElementById('hideMe') != null){document.getElementById('hideMe').style.visibility = 'hidden';document.getElementById('hideMe').style.display = 'none';}

How do I remove this?
What steps can I take to prevent this from occurring again?
How can I identify the susceptible area?

Thanks.

Comment: Wipe the system, restore from your backup, fix the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > How do I remove this?

- You need to restore from some backups.

> > What steps can I take to prevent this from occurring again?

The best ways which you can reduce the chance of getting a WP site hacked:

1. Change db table prefix to something else from WP default
2. Change WP default admin username to something else which no one can easily predict
3. Change the default admin dashboard  (`/wp-admin`) URL to something else, using `.htaccess` rules, which nobody can predict easily. If you are confused with `.htaccess` rules, use some addons like `stealth-login`

Actually, if this is just a WP hack, ideally you don't need to wipe out your entire system. Since, you don't know whether its a complete server hack or not, it is better to wipe out completely and restore from backups.